# Migrating tables from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Migration Wizard to copy some tables from SQL server to MySQL local instance. When I define the source and target connection and test them I get a Connection Successful message and the Fetch Schema List step also displays finished retrieving the schema. However when I go to the next step, it does not display the schema! Has anyone faced the issue? Since the connections to the source is successful, I am not able to find out what the issue is. Thanks.